# is test data used in Pycaret time series(beta) completely unseen by the model(s)?

Tags: python, time-series, pycaret

Post checking official [documentation](https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/time_series/api/time_series.html) and [example](https://nbviewer.org/github/pycaret/pycaret/blob/time_series_beta/time_series_101.ipynb), I am still confused if test data passed to the **setup** function is completely unseen by the model???

```
from pycaret.datasets import get_data
from pycaret.internal.pycaret_experiment import TimeSeriesExperiment

# get data
y = get_data('airline', verbose=False)

# no of future steps to forecast
fh = 12 # or alternately fh = np.arange(1,13)
fold = 3

# setup
exp = TimeSeriesExperiment()
exp.setup(data=y, fh=fh, fold = fold)
exp.models()
```

which gives description as:

[image]

Also, checked at cv-graph, we can conclude that *test data set is not used while cv*. But, Still as it's not mentioned anywhere about it, need a concrete evidence.

**Train-Test split**
[image]

**Train c-v splits**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice the cv splits, they do not use the test data at all. So any step such as `create_model`, `tune_model`, `blend_model`, `compare_models` that use Cross-Validation, will not use the test data at all for training.

Once you are happy with the models from these steps, you can finalize the model using `finalize_model`. In this case, whatever model you pass to `finalize_model` is trained on the complete dataset (train + test) so that you can make true future predictions.